# React Player Controls - HTML5 video event handlers not recognizing video object

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I'm new to the React framework, so I'm still learning JSX syntax and patterns.

I am attempting to hook a custom video control UI into an HTML5 video element, but to no avail.

I can get the individual PLAY and PAUSE buttons to control the video with a simple onClick function, but when I combine PLAY/PAUSE as a toggle element with the  component, I can't figure out how to combine the PLAY/PAUSE icon toggle events with my handlePlay()/handlePause() functions.

I'm sure this is a novice step that I am missing, but I am pretty much stuck here...any feedback will be much appreciated.

*EDIT: added this line inside "PlaybackControls" ( onClick={isPlaying ? console.log('PLAYING!') : console.log('PAUSED!')} )

The console.log() prints 'PLAYNING!' and 'PAUSED!' onClick event, as expected...but if I replace the console.log()s with calls to the "handlePlay()" and "handlePause()" functions...nothing happens.

What am I missing?

A sample of my code is listed below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { PlaybackControls, PlayButton, PauseButton, FormattedTime, 
TimeMarker, ProgressBar } from 'react-player-controls';

import customControls from './customControls.scss';

export default class Video01 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isPlayable: true,
      isPlaying: false,
      showPrevious: false,
      hasPrevious: false,
      showNext: false,
      hasNext: false
    }


    this.handlePlay = this.handlePlay.bind(this)
    this.handlePause = this.handlePause.bind(this)
}

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  componentWillMount() {

  }

/**********************************************************************\
    Video Playback Controls
\**********************************************************************/

    handlePlay () {
      if (this.props.isPlayable) {
        this.props.onPlaybackChange(true)
        this.refs.video01Ref.play()
      }
    }

    handlePause () {
      this.props.onPlaybackChange(false)
      this.refs.video01Ref.pause()
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

      <div className={styles.container} data-tid="container">

        <div className={styles.videoContainer} data-tid="videoContainer">

        <video ref="video01Ref" src="./video/myVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />

        </div>

        </div>

        <div className={customControls.ControlsWrapper}>

          <PlaybackControls className={customControls.PlayButton, customControls.PauseButton}
            isPlayable={this.state.isPlayable}
            isPlaying={this.state.isPlaying}
            showPrevious={false}
            hasPrevious={false}
            showNext={false}
            hasNext={false}
            onPlaybackChange={isPlaying => this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { isPlaying: isPlaying }))}
onClick={isPlaying ? console.log('PLAYING!') : console.log('PAUSED!')}

              />

              <ProgressBar className={customControls.ProgressBar} />

              <TimeMarker className={customControls.TimeMarker} />

            </div>

            </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bit of progress so I decided to answer my own question, in hopes of spurring some feedback from some good Samaritan React/JSX gurus.

I am still getting familiar with the React/JSX syntax, but I am really liking what I have learned so far. The modular approach is definitely much more efficient as it relates to memory/optimization...and it makes it much easier to pin-point bugs and errors. With that being said...here's what I discovered so far:

- I figured out how to play/pause my video via an external component (Custom Player Controls).
- I learned that it is wise to engineer my layout with individual(nested) components, as opposed to one large mess (i.e. ,  and  are individual components that are combined into a  class, which is then inserted into my  component, which is inserted into my  )

What I am still trying to figure out is how to pass props between components. The concept of States and Properties makes sense to me, but I am lacking some fundamental understanding of how to properly execute a workflow. I am sure it has something to do with React Life Cycles, but that's an entirely separate conversation.

For now, an example of my updated code is posted below. I am able to Play/Pause an HTML5 video with and external components (Custom Player Controls), but how to I pass the props  element back to the custom controls components? For example, how do I map the default  props (i.e. "currentTime", "duration", "seeking", "ended" => to the  "currentTime", "totalTime", "onSeek", etc.)?

Pardon my lengthy rant, but any feedback will be greatly appreciate. Here's my updated code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { PlaybackControls, PlayButton, PauseButton, FormattedTime, TimeMarker, TimeMarkerType, ProgressBar } from 'react-player-controls';

import customControls from './customControls.scss';

export default class CustomControls01 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isEnabled: true,
      isPlayable: true,
      isPlaying: false,
      showPrevious: false,
      hasPrevious: false,
      showNext: false,
      hasNext: false,
      totalTime: 28,
      currentTime: 0,
      bufferedTime: 0,
      isSeekable: true,
      lastSeekStart: 0,
      lastSeekEnd: 0,
      markerSeparator: ' / ',
      firstMarkerType: TimeMarkerType.ELAPSED,
      secondMarkerType: TimeMarkerType.DURATION,
    }

    this.handlePlay = this.handlePlay.bind(this)
    this.handlePause = this.handlePause.bind(this)
}

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {

    }

/**********************************************************************\
  Video Playback Controls
\**********************************************************************/

  handlePlay() {
    vid01.play()
  }

  handlePause() {
    vid01.pause()
  }

  render() {

    const { isPlayable, isPlaying, showPrevious, showNext, hasPrevious, hasNext, totalTime, currentTime, markerSeparator, firstMarkerType, secondMarkerType, bufferedTime, isSeekable, lastSeekStart, lastSeekEnd, lastIntent, className, extraClasses, childClasses, style, childrenStyles, onPlaybackChange } = this.props;

    const TimeMarkerType = {
      ELAPSED: 'ELAPSED',
      REMAINING: 'REMAINING',
      REMAINING_NEGATIVE: 'REMAINING_NEGATIVE',
      DURATION: 'DURATION',
    }

    return (

        <div className={customControls.ControlsWrapper}>

          <PlaybackControls className={customControls.PlayButton, customControls.PauseButton}
            isPlayable={this.state.isPlayable}
            isPlaying={this.state.isPlaying}
            showPrevious={false}
            hasPrevious={false}
            showNext={false}
            hasNext={false}
            onPlaybackChange={isPlaying => this.setState({ ...this.state, isPlaying }, isPlaying ? (vid01) => this.handlePlay(isPlaying, isPlayable) : (vid01) => this.handlePause(isPlaying, isPlayable))}
          />

          <ProgressBar className={customControls.ProgressBar}
            totalTime={this.state.totalTime}
            currentTime={this.state.currentTime}
            bufferedTime={this.state.bufferedTime}
            isSeekable={this.state.isSeekable}
            onSeek={time => this.setState((vid01) => ({ currentTime: time }))}
            onSeekStart={time => this.setState((vid01) => ({ lastSeekStart: time }))}
            onSeekEnd={time => this.setState((vid01) => ({ lastSeekEnd: time }))}
            onIntent={time => this.setState((vid01) => ({ lastIntent: time }))}
          />

          <TimeMarker className={customControls.TimeMarker}
            totalTime={this.state.totalTime}
            currentTime={this.state.currentTime}
            markerSeparator={this.state.markerSeparator}
            firstMarkerType={this.state.firstMarkerType}
            secondMarkerType={this.state.secondMarkerType}
          />

        </div>

    );
  }
}

CustomControls01.propTypes = {
};
```